# copy many files from subdirectories

Tags: r, file, copy, move, subdirectory

I am trying to copy/move files from many subdirectories into one folder:

```
new.folder <- "path/to/new/folder"
files <- basename(list.files(path, recursive = T))
file.copy(from=files, to=new.folder)
```

unfortunately I am gettin errors for all files:

```
In file.copy(from = files, to = new.folder):
  problem copying ./E202.fastq.gz to /path/to/new/folder/E202.fastq.gz: No such file or directory
```

I would appreciate any help, I am new to R.

Comment: Directory or the file doesn't exist.

Comment: can safe guard by creating the directory: dir.create(new.folder, recursive = T)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all files exist:

```
all(file.exists(files))
```

Otherwise, use `full.names = TRUE`

```
files <- list.files(path, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
```

Because if you don't, the files will be assumed to be in the current directory

```
getwd()
```

which may or may not be equivalent to `path`

Comment: I would love to but ..... how? It was my first question here so I'm still learning.